# PHP: How to escape HTML form input multidimensional keys

Tags: php, html

I have form that have input fields with multidimensional keys. And keys contains `XPath` queries.

When i submit my form, keys of array spoiling.

#### This is simple example of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php if (isset($_POST['key'])){
    var_dump($_POST['key']);
}

$attr = '//*[self::textarea or self::input]/@placeholder';
?>
<form action="" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="key[1][<?php echo $attr;?>]">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Response of `var_dump`

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["//*[self::textarea or self::input"]=>
    string(3) "asd"
  }
}
```

How can i escape keys. I hope someone can give an answer.

> Please do not offer to resolve this issue with json or with another way.

Comment: @DannyEbbers this is not related to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to escape the `$attr` value, and then use `array_walk` over `$_POST['key']` to replace the keys with their [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) version:

```
if (isset($_POST['key'])) {
    array_walk($_POST['key'], function (&$a) {
        $a = array(urldecode(key($a)) => current($a));
    });
}
var_dump($_POST);

$attr = '//*[self::textarea or self::input]/@placeholder';
?>
<form action="" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="key[1][<?php echo urlencode($attr);?>]">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["key"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["//*[self::textarea or self::input]/@placeholder"]=>
      string(3) "asd"
    }
  }
}
```

If you have multiple elements under each numeric `key` value, you will need to use a `foreach` within the `array_walk`:

```
if (isset($_POST['key'])) {
    array_walk($_POST['key'], function (&$a) {
        foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
            $a[urldecode($key)] = $value;
            unset($a[$key]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is good idea. but i need to find something without decoding. Anyways this is good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Yes sorry. I just forget to mention. So but your answer is really good.

Comment: @AaronYordanyan are you going to ask the question again?

Comment: its really very interesting case, and i think it's not handled never. But i just change my implementation way, so i'm using now your method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlspecialchars()`.

```
    <input type="text" name="key[1][<?php echo htmlspecialchars($attr);?>]">
```

Comment: This is not completely solve my problem. Its not working without decoding. Thanks for answer.